# Youtube javascript api onStateChange doesn't always work

Tags: javascript, youtube

As you can see on my site
http://www2.outofscopes.com/test/index.html

I'm trying to make the youtube API inform me of any event that is in `onStateChange` by alerting it. using the function below:

```js
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    videoId: '-cSFPIwMEq4',
    events: {
      'onStateChange': function (event) {

        alert(event.data);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

But both in chrome and firefox(mostly firefox), it alerts only sometimes when reloading the page.

Why would that happen?

Comment: not sure, but i think before set the function, you need to wait until frame load.

Comment: @siniradam what do u mean by before set the function?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this. http://jsfiddle.net/NrHdq/

```
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/-cSFPIwMEq4" onload="floaded()" title="YouTube video player" id="player" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="400" width="900"></iframe>

<script>
    //onYouTubePlayerAPIReady
    function floaded() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            videoId: '-cSFPIwMEq4',
            events: {
                'onStateChange': function (event) {

                    alert(event.data);
                }
            }
        });
    }

</script>

</body>
```

​